# Trying to measure strength of correlation among correlations

Tags: regression, t-test

Suppose I have a bunch of data on whether people like different TV shows. I have a bunch of data about whether particular viewers like particular TV shows.

For every viewer, I also have their answer (as a score from 1 to 5) to the question “How much does the quantity of explosions in TV shows you watch affect your enjoyment of the show?” And for every show, I have a score (again from 1 to 5) of how many explosions there are.

I want to see whether people are correct about whether they enjoy explosions in TV shows.

One approach would be: look for the correlation between rating and quantity of explosions on every user’s viewing history to get the strength of their preference for explosions, and then try to measure the correlation between this correlation strength and the user’s professed explosion preference. But this doesn’t take into account the fact that some users have rated more TV shows than others, and the users with more ratings should provide more evidence.

What is the best way to test this?

Comment: Maybe it's not just about quantity of explosions, maybe quality of explosions matters? Are people who like seeing explosions on TV going to enjoy watching a large number of "lame" explosions?

Comment: I don't know; maybe that's what I'm trying to determine here :P My data is actually in a different domain, this is just analogous to what I'm really working on.

Comment: You'll likely get better answers if you explain your real problem instead of this hypothetical one with explosions.

Comment: What's harder to understand about the hypothetical one?